# Menu item didn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

This is a wordpress site. I used hash(#) menu. I used one item for external link but it's not working.
Please check : http://gtmhospitality.biz/

and look at the last menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add `class="external"` to your `<a>` tag

So your code for external links must look like this

```
<li>
    <a href="http://getvr.com/" class="external">Getvr</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The #success-story won't work because you don't have an id with `success-story`, you do have two with `team` and the second team should be `success-story`.